# How do i send a mail along with image as attachment in c#?

Tags: c#

How do i send a mail along with image as attachment in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void SendMail(string email, string message)
        {
            // Algorithm :: A MailMessage object is created and the details such as FromAddress, ToAddress, Subject, Body are included and the mail is sent.
            MailMessage newmessage = new MailMessage();
            try
            {
                newmessage.From = new MailAddress("email", "subject");
                newmessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                newmessage.Subject = "Hii Friends..";
                newmessage.Body += message;
                newmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                //SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
                //client.Port = 587; yahoo port number

                client.EnableSsl = true;
                string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"logo.png");
                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my text , viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");

                LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path);
                logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
                AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br></body></html>" + message, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

                newmessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
                newmessage.AlternateViews.Add(av1);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("mail"))
                {
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail", "password");
                }
                client.Send(newmessage);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

MyMessage.From = new MailAddress(“EmailFrom”);
MyMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(“ToEmail”));

MyMessage.Subject = “EmailSubject”;
MyMessage.Body = “EmailBody”;

Attachment DailyAttachFile = new Attachment(“Full Image Path”);
MyMessage.Attachments.Add(DailyAttachFile);

SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(“SMTPServer”);
emailClient.Port = int.Parse(“SMTPServerPortNo”);
emailClient.Send(MyMessage);
MyMessage.Dispose();
```